# Get Logged in User Role: Asp.net MVC5

Tags: c#, asp.net, asp.net-identity

I have a doubt. I am using Asp.net mvc5 in VS2013. When the user is logged in, username of the logged in user can be identified using,

```
    User.Identity.GetUserId
```

But i couldn't be able to identify the role of the user in the view page.

I tried the following:

```
    @{
        var store = new Microsoft.AspNet.Identity.EntityFramework.UserStore<RaspberryPi.Models.ApplicationUser>(new RaspberryPi.Models.ApplicationDbContext());
        var manager = new Microsoft.AspNet.Identity.UserManager<RaspberryPi.Models.ApplicationUser>(store);
        var l = manager.IsInRole(User.Identity.GetUserId, "Moderator");
    }
```

But resulted in error.

```
    CS1928: 'Microsoft.AspNet.Identity.UserManager<RaspberryPi.Models.ApplicationUser>' does not contain a definition for 'IsInRole' and the best extension method overload 'Microsoft.AspNet.Identity.UserManagerExtensions.IsInRole<TUser>(Microsoft.AspNet.Identity.UserManager<TUser>, string, string)' has some invalid arguments
```

How can i do that?

Please help,
Thanks

Comment: What was the error that you saw?

Comment: Don't mean to sound rude but the exception is pretty self explanatory.

Comment: @James I tried,. but couldn't get it to work.

Comment: Does your ApplicationUser derive from IdentityUser?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The exception is pretty self explanatory really, the parameters you are providing do not tie up with the [IsInRole](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/dn497502%28v=vs.108%29.aspx) extension method.

The problem (assuming your code is *exactly* as you have shown) is that`GetUserId` is a *function*, not a property, therefore you need to actually call it

```
manager.IsInRole(User.Identity.GetUserId(), "Moderator");
```

Answer (score 1):

Does your ApplicationUser derive from IdentityUser?

```
public class ApplicationUser : IdentityUser
```

This should work in the cshtml

```
@{
    var context = new RaspberryPi.Models.ApplicationDbContext();          
    if (context.Users.Any(u => u.UserName == User.Identity.Name))
    {
        var store = new Microsoft.AspNet.Identity.EntityFramework.UserStore<applicationuser>();
        var manager = new Microsoft.AspNet.Identity.UserManager<applicationuser>(store);
        ApplicationUser user = manager.FindByName<applicationuser>(User.Identity.Name);
        if (manager.IsInRole(user.Id, "Moderator") == true)
        {
        // Do whatever you want...
        }
    }
```

Or if you want to do it the simple way just do this.

```
@if (User.IsInRole("Moderator")){
}
```